# Suspension spring movement Unity

Tags: unity-game-engine

I was wondering if there is a chance to make a realistic suspension spring movent in unity. [image]

If thought that changing the scale would be good, but it is not working. Any idea?

Comment: You mean just animation of spring compression? Or physical simulation?

Comment: I don't know exactly. The project I have is to simulate the front suspension and the steering system of a car. I will try to make my project as physical as possible. Which is the easiest?

Comment: That is too broad a question to answer. If you are no clear on the project yourself, make sure you clarify that first. At the moment this question isn't answerable.

Comment: I 've cleared it in my head and the answer is physical simulation.

Comment: This might be better asked at [http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/](http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/). Car simulations of varying realism are often found in games, so I think gamedevs could give some interesting answers.